# How to solve (or name) this knapsack-like algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

Let's assume I own a store & only sell items in groups of two.

1. If I sell a PENCIL and an ERASER, I earn $3
2. If I sell a PENCIL and a MARBLE , I earn $2
3. If I sell a RULER and an ERASER, I earn $2

Each customer is willing to buy up to 1 item of each & I want to maximize profit. Therefore, selling #1 AND #2 is illegal because that would be 2 pencils. #1 AND #3 would is also illegal due to the erasers. So, legal moves are: only #1, only #2, only #3, or #2 AND #3. Since the last option has a profit of $5, I should do that.

How would I solve this problem in polynomial time? If it is np-hard, what heuristic might get me close? If nothing else, does this problem have a name?

Comment: What have you tried? We're willing to help with your homework, but you need to show an effort :)

Comment: My only thought is a nested loop (for every group that includes a pencil, for every group that involves a ruler....) but that grows pretty quickly. No worries about cheating me out of learning, it's actually something I'm building on top of a hungarian algo for a vehicle routing problem.

Comment: What are the restrictions? It seems like should just always sell 2&3 to each customer, I may not be understanding thew question fully

Comment: This would be a [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) problem.

Comment: Parker & Ryan, I pass in a restricted candidate list into this algo (eg marble + ruler was already deemed infeasible). The only difference between this & the real situation is that instead of 4 items, there is an array of about 1000 items making up an RCL of 10,000 combinations.

Comment: Felix, that was my first thought, but I got hung up because I'm visualizing it as multiple knapsacks all with space == 1. Conceptually, how would I approach it?

Comment: @FelixCastor DP isn't a class of problems, it's a class of algorithms - for all problems that can be solved with DP, there also exists an algorithm that isn't DP

Comment: Seems like a variant of min 2SAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching in general (non-bipartite) graphs, solvable in polynomial time by the [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm).

Comment: I like this idea, and forgive me if I'm mistaken,  but by nature isn't the blossom algo a maximum matching? For example, if pencil AND eraser earned $100, it would be incorrect, right?

Comment: @MattK It's the weighted variant. See the end of the Wikipedia article.